# Correlated Normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

Consider a number $X$ being selected according to normal distribution 
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}exp\left[-\frac{X^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right]$.
Suppose the outcome is $X_1$. Then, a new number $Y$ is picked according to probability distribution $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}}exp\left[-\frac{(Y-X_1)^2}{2 \sigma^2}\right]$. Lets say it is $Y_1$.

What can be said about the average of the quantity $(Y_1-X_1)^2$?

Comment: Maybe add self-study tag? Your friend is the double expectation theorem!

Comment: @Kjetil Is that a different name for the law of total expectation?

Comment: @Glen_b: Yes, it is. Seems to have many names ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen  Even after studying the theorem mentioned by you I am still unsure about how to compute basic quantities like E[Y1]. Could you kindly explain in some detail?

Comment: In the second density you wrote $\mu^2$ where I suppose you meant $\sigma^2$. I corrected it. If you really meant $\mu^2$, please explain why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have $X \sim \cal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Then $Y \mid X=X_1 \sim \cal{N}(X_1, \sigma^2)$. Remember the double expectation theorem says that
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}  
     \E \E [Y \mid X] = \E Y
$$
Using this we can compute
$$
\E (Y-X_1)^2 = \E \E [(Y-X_1)^2 \mid X_1] = \E [\sigma^2 \mid X_1] = \sigma^2
$$